# Scale content of an iframe for preview

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transforms

I have an iframe that previews a page on my site. It has a smaller size than the page and I would like to be able to have the content of the page to be scaled to the size of it like if it was zoomed. Is it possible? I saw some chrome extensions with similar functionality. I looked around and was not able to find a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem through jQuery Zoomer plugin http://dev.hubspot.com/blog/bid/89755/jQuery-Zoomer-Zoom-up-your-iFrames

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but you can probably try using the "zoom" property.

[Here](http://www.css3.com/css-zoom/)